# Sard's theorem for superharmonic functions: less regularity required?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, potential-theory

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ must be at least $C^d$ in order to guarantee in general that
$$\{\phi\in \mathbb{R}|\,\exists x\in \mathbb{R}^d:\,f(x)=\phi,\,(\nabla f)(x)=0\}$$
is a zero-measure set.

I was wondering whether that $C^d$-requirement can not be relaxed if we assume that $f$ is sub- or superharmonic too?

Intuitively, the mean value property / Hopf Lemma seems to prohibit a large (image of) critical set. Also, by analysing the volume-expansion of the gradient flow $\dot{x}=-(\nabla f)(x)$, I think one can deduce that each level set of $f$ (strictly below $f$'s maximum though) has some points where $\nabla f$ doesn't vanish, provided that $f$ is $C^{1,1}$, superharmonic and the sets $S_{\phi}:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d|\,f(x)\geq \phi\}$ have finite volume.

Comment: What is $C^{1,1}$?

Comment: Continuously differentiable with derivatives that are Lipschitz continuous (though local Lipschitz continuity suffices).